# Will other threads block in this code with CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I am new in CUDA programming and have a strange behaviour.

I have a kernel like this:

```
__global__ void myKernel (uint64_t *input, int numOfBlocks, uint64_t *state) {

  int const t = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < numOfBlocks; i++) {
    if (t < 32) {
      if (t < 8) {
        state[t] = state[t] ^ input[t];
      }
      if (t < 25) {
        deviceFunc(device_state); /* will use some printf() */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I run this kernel with this parameter:
myKernel<<<1, 32>>>(input, numOfBlocks, state);

If 'numOfBlocks' is equal to 1, it will work fine, I get the result I expect back and the printf() inside the deviceFunc() are in the correct order.

If 'numOfBlocks' is equal to 2, it does not work fine! The result is not that what I expected and the printf() are not in the correct order (I only use printf() from thread 0)!

So, my question is now: The left threads from (32-25) which ARE NOT calling deviceFunc(), will they wait and block and this position or will they run the again and start over with the next for-loop iteration? I always thought that every line in the kernel is synchronized in the same block.

Comment: I have a serial version of my code which result equal results for some input M with only 1 'numOfBlocks'. If I use another input M' with 2 'numOfBlocks' the result is different from my serial code.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum sized, full reproducer of your problem? Without it, it would be impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I worked the whole day on this and I finally found a solution. First, you are right that I had in my deviceFunc() many RAW hazards. I started to put some __syncthreads() after any WRITE operation, but I think this slows down my program. And I don't think that __syncthreads() is the common way to resolve them. Funny is, that the result is still the same with and without __syncthreads().

But my problem in my code above is that I used

```
input[t]
```

which was wrong, because I had to include 'numOfBlocks' in my calculation of index:

```
input[(NUM_OF_XOR_THREADS * i) + t)
```

Now, the result was correct and my problem is solved.